# (MalformedXML) when calling the PutBucketReplication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, replication

I'm trying to put a bucket replication **cross account** by AWS CLI:

> aws s3api put-bucket-replication --bucket "mybucket"
>   --replication-configuration "{\"Role\": \"arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/buckets-replication\", \"Rules\": [{
>        \"Status\": \"Enabled\", \"Priority\": 1, \"DeleteMarkerReplication\":
>        { \"Status\": \"Enabled\" }, \"Destination\": { \"Bucket\":
>        \"arn:aws:s3:::mybucket-destination\", \"AccessControlTranslation\": {
>        \"Owner\": \"Destination\" } } }]}" --region "eu-west-1" --profile
>        default

and I get this error:

> An error occurred (MalformedXML) when calling the PutBucketReplication
>   operation: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not
>   validate against our published schema

The corresponding Xml is:

```
<ReplicationConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
   <Role>string</Role>
   <Rule>
      <Status>string</Status>
      <Priority>integer</Priority>
      <DeleteMarkerReplication>
         <Status>string</Status>
      </DeleteMarkerReplication>
      <Destination>
         <Bucket>string</Bucket>
         <AccessControlTranslation>
            <Owner>string</Owner>
         </AccessControlTranslation>
      </Destination>
   </Rule>
</ReplicationConfiguration>
```

I really don't see what is wrong in the syntax. I followed this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutBucketReplication.html#AmazonS3-PutBucketReplication-request-Role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that

> ```
> <DeleteMarkerReplication>
>      <Status>string</Status>
> </DeleteMarkerReplication>
> ```

is required, even if set to Disabled.